# Objective-C: Return the UIView another UIView's center point is overlapping?

Tags: objective-c, ios

I am dragging a UIView around the screen and when the UIView's center overlaps another UIView, view Y, I'd like view Y to be returned.

Is there a method in Objective-C for doing it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do what you're loving for. If you're using a UiPanGesture instead of touchesMoved just move the if statement.

```
- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    [ViewA setCenter:[[touches anyObject] locationInView:self.view]];

    if (CGRectContainsPoint(ViewB.frame,viewA.center)){
         // Do something with ViewB
    }
}
```

Comment: I have several different views that this main view could possibly touch. Is this the simplest way to check for which uiview was passed over?

Comment: This is by far the simplest way. THis is the basis for all collision detection. It only gets more complicated from here.